# Join two list in R by id

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have something like this:

```
ids <- c("A","B","C")
ls <- list()
ls[[1]] <- c("aa","aaa")
ls[[2]] <- c("bb","bbb")
ls[[3]] <- c("cc","ccc")
```

and I would like to obtain something like the next:

```
data.frame(ids = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"), ls = c("aa","aaa","bb","bbb","cc","ccc"))
```

Would you know how to do it?
The length of each element of the ls can vary, but the length of the ids and ls is the same.
Dplyr and purrr(tidyverse) is Ok for me

Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest base R method is to use `unlist` and `rep` like this:

```
data.frame(ids=rep(ids, lengths(ls)), ls=unlist(ls))
  ids  ls
1   A  aa
2   A aaa
3   B  bb
4   B bbb
5   C  cc
6   C ccc
```

`rep` repeats the ids in varying lengths with the length of each list element calculated by `lengths`. Then the nested list is converted to a vector with `unlist`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
library(tidyr)
gather(data.frame(setNames(ls, ids)), ids, ls)
  ids  ls
1   A  aa
2   A aaa
3   B  bb
4   B bbb
5   C  cc
6   C ccc
```

This works in the following way: first, I assign the names to the list:

```
named_list <- setNames(ls, ids)
named_list
$A
[1] "aa"  "aaa"
$B
[1] "bb"  "bbb"
$C
[1] "cc"  "ccc"
```

Then convert it to a dataframe:

```
test_df <- data.frame(named_list)
test_df
    A   B   C
1  aa  bb  cc
2 aaa bbb ccc
```

And then I reshape it using either `tidyr::gather` or `reshape2::melt`

```
gather(test_df)
  key value
1   A    aa
2   A   aaa
3   B    bb
4   B   bbb
5   C    cc
6   C   ccc
```

To supply your column names, just add `ids` and `ls` as above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `base R`

```
setNames(stack(setNames(ls, LETTERS[1:3]))[2:1], c("ids", "ls"))
#   ids  ls
#1   A  aa
#2   A aaa
#3   B  bb
#4   B bbb
#5   C  cc
#6   C ccc
```